# Qt - how to send QByteArray to QserialPort

Tags: qt

i have **QByteArray** variable like this:

```
QByteArray ba;
ba.resize(100);
ba.fill(0x00);
ba[0] = 0x01;
ba[8] = 0x0a;
```

now i want write **ba** variable to QSerialPort. how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble sending Data with QSerialPort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18806001/trouble-sending-data-with-qserialport)

Comment: not work for me !

Comment: Hi there, can you show us how you're setting up the `QSerialPort` as well as how you're using it? You may also want to check out [_the documentation_](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html) and [_the `write` member function_](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write-2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First open a serial-port with QSerialport and open it , then you can write this code

```
 serialport.write(ba);
 serialport.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

QSerialPort is a QIODevice so...

QIODevice::open(QIODevice::ReadWrite) 
Then
QIODevice::write(ba); 
... with your serial port object.